# Android ROM building from AOSP... do I need to worry about drivers?

Tags: android, drivers, rom

I need to build my own rom for a specific device. I get how how to download and build the AOSP stuff, but wonder if flashing the system.img file over an existing one on a device will work without issue or if I need to do something with drivers? Where exactly are the drivers? Should I be pulling out specific folders from a rooted devices system folder and copy them into the new AOSP system file??

Just looking for some clarity on the process.

Comment: Yes, you need to worry about it. But first you should download and build the source and then worry about the drivers when you did that.

Comment: In progress... just trying to plan ahead.

Comment: What AOSP are you using? 4.0.X?

Comment: I was planning on Froyo as the device I am targeting is built with froyo. If the drivers dont present too much of an issue, I would be more than happy to have it use ICS but I have no idea if that would just add miles to the path I am at the foot of...

Comment: You need the drivers before compiling ICS, but Froyo should work out of the box. Maybe you can extract binary drivers from the Stock Rom - but as the kernel is licensed under the GPL, there *should* be an official driver binary from the manufacturer.

Comment: Ok, so... if I use Froyo, I dont need to add any drivers, I make any changes to the build I want, 'make' it all, then just flash over the newly created system.img to the device and viola. For ICS, I would basically extract all the /system/bin and /system/lib binary files and throw them into the /vendor/$VENDOR/$DEVICE/proprietary folder of the build, make, flash over, etc..??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9535/discussion-between-force-and-mindwire)

Comment: Force, just pinging to see if you are around to chat more?